# Projective dimension of ring over its center

Tags: homological-algebra, noncommutative-algebra, projective-modules, homological-dimension, noncommutative-rings

If $A$ is a ring and $Z(A)$ is its center then what is a sufficient condition for the projective dimension of $A$ over $Z(A)$ *(ie: $pd_{Z(A)}(A)$)* to be finite?

(Assuming that $A\neq Z(A)$).

Comment: The silly answer: A being commutative.

Comment: What if we assume $Z(A)\neq A$?

Comment: @CSA: You could ask that $Z(A)$ has finite global dimension. Perhaps explaining what example you have in mind may help us to give you a more useful sufficient condition.